# Distribution of the sum of two (dependent?) random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

There are two random variables $X$ and $Y$, each of which can take on the values $0$ or $1$. Furthermore:

- $P(X=0,Y=0)=p$,
- $P(X=0)=1/2$
- and $P(Y=0)=1/2$.

So these two shouldn't be independent in general, since $\frac{1}{2}^2$ is not necessarily $p$. The distributions of the 2 variables look like this

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
x & P(X=x) \\
\hline
0 & 1/2 \\
1 & 1/2 \\
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
y & P(Y=y) \\
\hline
0 & 1/2 \\
1 & 1/2 \\
\end{array}
$$

Now what does the distribution of $X+Y$ look like? If I just add them, the sum surpasses $1$.
I [found a formula](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf) for *independent* variables, but the ones in this example aren't.

> Edit:
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{c|cc}
> z & P(Z=z) \\
> \hline
> 0 & p \\
> 1 & 1-2p \\
> 2 & p \\
> \end{array}
> $$

Comment: Hint: Compute the distribution of (X,Y).

Comment: @Did I'm just guessing now, since I'm new to probability, but something like this?

Comment: Quote: `...the distribution of (X,Y)`, not of X+Y.

Comment: @Did Alright, following [this](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_1_1_joint_pmf.php), I get something similar, namely $P(0,0)=p$, $P(1,0)=1/2-p$, $P(0,1)=1/2-p$, $P(1,1)=p$. Correct?

Comment: And **now** you can deduce from this (which you do not explain how you proved it...) the distribution of X+Y.

Comment: @Did For instance, if I want to find out $P(X=1,Y=0)$, I need to subtract from the cases where $Y=0$ the the cases where $X$ is $0$, too (probability-wise). I really can't think of another way, except maybe multiplying the respective probabilities for the variables to be 0 or 1. Or are you saying that what I edited in *is* the solution?

Comment: What I am saying is that if P(X=0,Y=0)=p, P(X=1,Y=0)=1/2−p, P(X=0,Y=1)=1/2−p and P(X=1,Y=1)=p, then P(X+Y=0)=p, P(X+Y=1)=1-2p and P(X+Y=2)=p. But that, for your solution to be  complete, you should show how P(X=0,Y=0)=p, P(X=0)=1/2
and P(Y=0)=1/2, implies that P(X=0,Y=0)=p, P(X=1,Y=0)=1/2−p, P(X=0,Y=1)=1/2−p and P(X=1,Y=1)=p.

Comment: @Did I see, I think I can show that more rigorously than in my previous comment, thanks a lot!